# Serde class for custom JSON (Kotlin & Kafka)

Tags: kotlin, serialization, apache-kafka-streams

I am writting a kafka stream application in Kotlin, which consumes a JSON message (no AVRO or Schema Registry).

In MyMessage.kt I have declared the `MyMessage` class as `@Serializable`.

**MyMessage.kt**

```
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class MyMessage(val from: String, val to: String, val msg: String)
```

**Streaming.kt**

```
val s: KString<String, MyMessage> = streamsBuilder()
    .stream("my", Consumed.with(Serdes.String, Serdes.serdeFrom(MyMessage::class.java)
```

When running this I get the following error on the above line:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown class for built-in serializer. Supported types are: String, Short, Integer, Long, Float, Double, ByteArray, ByteBuffer, Bytes, UUID
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument for `Serdes.serdesFrom()` expects a `Serializer` and `Deserializer` object (both interfaces are Kafka interfaces from package `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization` and have nothing to do with the `@Serializable` annotation.

You need to create classes `MyMessageSerializer extends Serializer` and `MyMessageDeserialzer extends Deserializer` and pass those object into the method.
To implement the actual serialization / deserialization with both the classes you may rely on the default serialization / deserialization if you want.